# Android viewpager does not show layouts

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

In my Android application I'm using **viewpager** and **FragmentActivity**. But it does not show the content.

My FragmentActivity is:

```
public class DropPickup extends FragmentActivity {

private DPAdapter myAdapter;
private ViewPager myPager;



 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        myAdapter = new DPAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
 
        myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.dp_viewpager);
        myPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
 
 
 public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }
 
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
 
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new PickUpFragment();
            case 1:
                return new DropFragment();
 
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my page adapter is as below.

```
public DPAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        return new PickUpFragment();
        
    case 1:
        return new DropFragment();
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 2;
}
```

This is one of my fragments

```
public class DropFragment extends Fragment {

TableLayout DTbl;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View viewx=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drop, container, false);
    DTbl = (TableLayout) viewx.findViewById(R.id.dpp_tbl_prs_tbl);
    
    
    
    //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    return viewx;
}

}
```

This is my layout view pager

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/dp_viewpager"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

What can I try to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of writing two separate classes **MyAdapter** & **DPAdapter** when they are same so, drop one of them. Otherwise your code is looking fine.

**Update**

Use this code and keep MyAdapter class

```
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.dp_viewpager);
        myPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

**Here is my code how I use viewpager**

```
public class Book extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "A", "B", "C"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.book);


        FragmentStatePagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        pager.setCurrentItem(CONTENT.length);
    }

    class MyFragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public MyFragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

if(CONTENT[position].equals("A"))
{
 return Page1.newInstance(CONTENT[position]);
} else{
               return Page2.newInstance(CONTENT[position]);
            }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
          return CONTENT.length;
        }
    }
}
```

where Page1 and Page2 are fragments